# Html5 Canvas concept

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm currently learning the basics of html5 canvas. I just ran into something that needs to be explain. I have this code.

```
function myApp() {

        this.el = document.getElementById('canvas');
        this.context = this.el.getContext('2d');
        this.colors = ['#fff', '#000', '#f00'];

        this.init();
}

myApp.prototype = {

        init: function() {

            var _this = this;

            _this.draw();
        },

        draw: function() {

            var _this = this;

            _this.context.fillStyle = _this.colors[2];
            _this.context.fillRect(10,10,100,100);
            //_this.context.fillStyle = _this.colors[2];
        }

}

var startThisBitch = new myApp();
```

If I try to fillStyle() after I create the Rect(), there's nothing on my canvas. But if I fill the color BEFORE creating the Rect(), it works. I just don't find it logical. Or maybe I'm missing the concept. Do you guys have any explainations?

Comment: I have not technical answer for this, only that it makes sense to me. You choose how you want it to look before "painting" it onto the canvas, otherwise you would have to redraw the canvas with the new color, after you already "painted" it on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I just don't find it logical.

Would you find it logical to *first* paint a wall, and *then* choose the color of the paint?

Edit: fillStyle() doesn't actually draw anything, it just sets the parameters of subsequent draw calls. fillRect() however *does* draw pixels on canvas, so it's necessary to set all parameters (color, line width, etc.) *before* calling fillRect().

Comment: Fair enough sir. Thanks.